# Regarding-SearchView in Actionbar

Tags: android

I implemented a searchView in Actionbar

```
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(
            R.id.search_item).getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {

            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

What i wanted is that after submitting the text , the searchView should become readonly.
i have tried `searchView.setEnabled(false);` but didnt get ..Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onQueryTextSubmit() Method: add this

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                searchView.invalidate();
```

and to remove it use this:

```
if(searchView.getInputType()==InputType.TYPE_NULL) {
        searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        searchView.invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: i have changed it in my answer. check it now

Comment: where have you added that removing one code with if condition

Comment: after 
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(
            R.id.search_item).getActionView();

Comment: put code in : searchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {